Getting Wrong ABI for the openbrush contracts
openbrush Library

when I am building the openbrush examples i am getting wrong ABI for the input of all the functions that are in the libraray.
Can anyone tell why it is happening.
e.g.
This is in the ABI file for the revoke_role function
{
        "args": [
          {
            "label": "role",
            "type": {
              "displayName": [
                "accesscontrol_external",
                "RevokeRoleInput1"
              ],
              "type": 0
            }
          },
          {
            "label": "account",
            "type": {
              "displayName": [
                "accesscontrol_external",
                "RevokeRoleInput2"
              ],
              "type": 16
            }
          }
        ],
        "default": false,
        "docs": [],
        "label": "AccessControl::revoke_role",
        "mutates": true,
        "payable": false,
        "returnType": {
          "displayName": [
            "ink",
            "MessageResult"
          ],
          "type": 18
        },
        "selector": "0x6e4f0991"
},

and this is the function
fn revoke_role(&mut self, role: RoleType, account: Option<AccountId>) -> Result<(), AccessControlError> {
}


Openbrush is no longer maintaining it as I'm aware, pendzl is :https://github.com/Pendzl/pendzl
